# 'NoneType' object is not callable error during pip rpy2 installation on ubuntu

Tags: r, python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-20.04, rpy2

I have a pip3 installation error when trying to install the rpy2 python package. Here is the complete output:

```
~$ sudo pip3 install rpy2
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:116: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.23ubuntu1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:116: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.1.36ubuntu1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
Collecting rpy2
  Using cached rpy2-3.4.5.tar.gz (194 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ligu6s6s/rpy2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ligu6s6s/rpy2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-ligu6s6s/rpy2/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ligu6s6s/rpy2/
    Complete output (32 lines):
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:116: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.23ubuntu1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
      warnings.warn(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:116: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.1.36ubuntu1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
      warnings.warn(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
      warnings.warn(
    rpy2/_rinterface_cffi_build.py:258: UserWarning: /tmp/pip-install-ligu6s6s/rpy2/.eggs/cffi-1.15.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/_cffi_backend.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: failed to map segment from shared object
      warnings.warn(str(e))
    rpy2/_rinterface_cffi_build.py:268: UserWarning: /tmp/pip-install-ligu6s6s/rpy2/.eggs/cffi-1.15.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/_cffi_backend.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: failed to map segment from shared object
      warnings.warn(str(e))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ligu6s6s/rpy2/setup.py", line 199, in <module>
        setup(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 453, in __init__
        _Distribution.__init__(
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 292, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 831, in finalize_options
        ep(self)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 852, in _finalize_setup_keywords
        ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ligu6s6s/rpy2/.eggs/cffi-1.15.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 219, in cffi_modules
        add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ligu6s6s/rpy2/.eggs/cffi-1.15.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 57, in add_cffi_module
        ffi = ffi()      # maybe it's a function instead of directly an ffi
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
    ['cffi>=1.10.0', 'jinja2', 'pytz', 'tzlocal']
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Ubuntu version is 20.04.1 LTS
Python version is 3.8.10
pip 20.0.2
rpy2 version is 3.4.5 (I also tried with former versions: 3.4.3, 3.3.3)

Do you have any idea about the cause of this error?

Thank you.

Comment: I am still running into this :/ Anyone figured this out yet? :)

Answer (score 0):

This might not work for everyone, but it made it work on Ubuntu 22.04 for me:

```
python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade
python3 -m pip install setuptools --upgrade
python3 -m pip install wheel --upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

It seems to be some kind of mismatch between the `cffi` version that ships with the default Python installation and the `cffi` version which `rpy2` expects (but don't quote me on that).

Anyway, I also recommend looking at the setup scripts in their [Docker build](https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2-docker/blob/master/base/Dockerfile) and reproducing everything in them in case of other installation problems.

Edit: Not sure if necessary, but also make sure you have the latest version of the `cffi` Python package installed (`1.15.1` at the time of writing).

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading cffi to 1.14.3 helped in my case.